# PHP Trader macd returns false

Tags: php, php-extension, trading

I want to use trader_macd but it returns always `false`.
I am using the default parameters:

```
$data = [
0 => "0.06945900",
1 => "0.06945200",
2 => "0.06948100",
3 => "0.06944100",
4 => "0.06939800",
5 => "0.06941800",
6 => "0.06942300",
7 => "0.06940000",
8 => "0.06937700",
9 => "0.06937200",
10 => "0.06940000",
11 => "0.06939800",
12 => "0.06941100",
13 => "0.06944500",
14 => "0.06940100",
15 => "0.06942600",
16 => "0.06941500",
17 => "0.06941400",
18 => "0.06939900",
19 => "0.06941400",
20 => "0.06940700",
21 => "0.06938100",
22 => "0.06940400",
23 => "0.06937400",
24 => "0.06937000",
25 => "0.06939700"]

$result = trader_macd($data, 12, 26, 9)
```

When I set the last parameter ($signalPeriod) then get an array with `0` values:

```
0 => array:1 [▼
  24 => -0.0
]
1 => array:1 [▼
  24 => -0.0
]
2 => array:1 [▼
  24 => -0.0
]
```

When I am using other methods like trader_ema with same `$data` it works fine.

I also set `trader.real_precision` to `8`.

```
ini_set('trader.real_precision', '8');
```

What I am doing wrong?

My Systems uses php 7.2.7 with trader 0.5.0.

Comment: PHP 2 from ~1997? Really?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I just changed it to 7.2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough data to calculate the signal line you chose (9 day EMA of MACD line). Add eight more entries to your data array, and you'll get a result. Or lower the signal line period